# Integrate Signed Hash into original PDF

Tags: hash, itext, digital-signature

I am integrating a signed hash in an original PDF, and I still have an error on the validity of the signature. it's say that a pdf has been changed after signing.

below the steps: I calculate the hash then I send it for signature and finally I get the hash sign and I proceed to the integration in the original pdf

```
package com.example.hashdocument;

import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.*;
import com.lexpersona.commons.utils.ProcessLauncher;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.*;


public class Test2 {

    private static final String SRC = "B:/Hash-et-Reconstitution/tmp/Doc_test.pdf";
    private static final String DST = "B:/Hash-et-Reconstitution/tmp/Doc_test_DST.pdf";
    private static final String HASH = "B:/Hash-et-Reconstitution/tmp/Doc_test_hashed.hash";
    
    private static final String PATH_BAT = "C:/Repo_LP7/lpcommand.bat";
    private static final String PIN = "123456";
    private static final String CERTIFICATE = "C:/lp7command/tools/certificate.p12";
    private static final String SIGNED_HASH = "B:/Hash-et-Reconstitution/tmp/doc_signed.hash";
    
    private static byte[] readFileToByteArray(File file){
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        byte[] bArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        try{
          fis = new FileInputStream(file);
          fis.read(bArray);
          fis.close();                   
        }catch(IOException ioExp){
          ioExp.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bArray;
      }
    public static File bytesToFile(byte[] fileByte,String pathFile)  {
        File file = new File(pathFile);
        try {
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            os.write(fileByte);
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file;
    }
    public static byte[] signDocument() throws IOException {
        
        
        ProcessLauncher p = new ProcessLauncher(System.out, System.err);
        int exec;
        exec = p.exec("cmd.exe /c "+PATH_BAT+" <nul "+ SIGNED_HASH +" "+ PIN+" "
                + HASH+" "+CERTIFICATE, null, null);

        byte[] signedHash = readFileToByteArray(new File(SIGNED_HASH));
        
        return signedHash;
    }
     
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, DocumentException {
        
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream  os = null;
        String hash_document = "";
        
        InputStream data = null;
        int contentEstimated = 8192;

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SRC);

        reader.unethicalreading = true;
        reader.setAppendable(true);

        int pdfPagenumber = 1;

        pdfPagenumber = reader.getNumberOfPages(); // Sign on last page

        os = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', null, true);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();        
        appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();        
        appearance.setSignDate(cal);
        //appearance.setAcro6Layers(false);
        appearance.setReason("Signature de contrat");
        appearance.setLocation("MAROC");              
        appearance.setImage(null);
        appearance.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(300, 300, 20, 20);        
        appearance.setVisibleSignature(rect, pdfPagenumber, null);

        HashMap<PdfName, Integer> exc = new HashMap<PdfName, Integer>();
        exc.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new Integer(contentEstimated * 2 + 2));
        PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        dic.setReason(appearance.getReason()); 
        dic.setLocation(appearance.getLocation());
        dic.setContact(appearance.getContact());
        dic.setDate(new PdfDate(appearance.getSignDate()));
        appearance.setCryptoDictionary(dic);

        appearance.preClose(exc);

        data = appearance.getRangeStream();    

        MessageDigest messageDigest;
        String provider = null;
        String hashAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithms.SHA256;
        if (provider == null){
            messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(hashAlgorithm);
        }else {
            messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(hashAlgorithm,provider);
        }


        int read = 0;
        byte[] buff = new byte[contentEstimated];

        while ((read = data.read(buff, 0, contentEstimated)) > 0)
        {
            messageDigest.update(buff,0,read);                      
        }
        byte[] hashDigest = messageDigest.digest();

        byte[] documentHash = org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex.encode(hashDigest);

        //eSign Start        
        hash_document = new String(documentHash, "UTF-8");        
        System.out.println("Document Hash :"+hash_document);
        

        
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(HASH));
        out.print(hash_document);
        
        
        byte[] hashdocumentByte = signDocument();
        
        //////////////////// ADD SIGNED BYTES/HASH TO PDF DOCUMENT.      
        int contentEstimated2 = 8192;
        byte[] paddedSig = new byte[contentEstimated2];
        byte[] signedDocByte = hashdocumentByte;
        
        System.arraycopy(signedDocByte, 0, paddedSig, 0, signedDocByte.length);
        
        PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();
        dic2.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(paddedSig).setHexWriting(true));

        appearance.close(dic2);
        
        try(OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(DST)) {
            os.writeTo(outputStream);
        }

        os.close(); 
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share a PDF signed by you for analysis.

Comment: This is the signed document : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bYlc1NAbIQMcoj252rOnTfNS0ZC8BQG1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Having inspected the PDF a bit I think the CMS signature container by itself is alright, it merely signs a hash different from the hash of the signed byte ranges of the document. Do you still have the output of `System.out.println("Document Hash :"+hash_document);` for the document you shared? Or could you create yet another signed document with your code and also share the program output?

Comment: Thanks for your help.

here is the hash to sign : Document Hash :79793c58489eb94a17c365445622b7f7945972a5a0bc4c93b6444bedffa5a5bb

And this is the output of signing function before sign :
Hash to sign : 79793c58489eb94a17c365445622b7f7945972a5a0bc4c93b6444bedffa5a5bb

Finally this is the signed document  : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bYlc1NAbIQMcoj252rOnTfNS0ZC8BQG1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your output `79793c58489eb94a17c365445622b7f7945972a5a0bc4c93b6444bedffa5a5bb` is correct. But your signature container signs `A8BCBC6F9619ECB950864BFDF41D1B5B7CD33D035AF95570C426CF4B0405949B`. Thus, the problem is not in the code your show but apparently in `signDocument()` which does not seem to sign the hash you calculated.

Comment: Ah, `signDocument()` hashes the hex encoding of the calculated hash, `A8BCBC6F9619ECB950864BFDF41D1B5B7CD33D035AF95570C426CF4B0405949B` represents the hash of the byte array `"79793c58489eb94a17c365445622b7f7945972a5a0bc4c93b6444bedffa5a5bb".getBytes()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what do you think abous this code : First i calculate the hash and send to server A for signature

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SRC);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(TEMP);
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "sig");
    //appearance.setCertificate(chain[0]);
    ExternalSignatureContainer external = new 
    ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
    MakeSignature.signExternalContainer(appearance, external, 8192);

    InputStream inp = appearance.getRangeStream();  

    BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();


     byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(inp, digest.getMessageDigest("SHA256"));
     System.out.println("hash to sign : "+ hash);
     bytesToFile(hash, HASH);
     byte[] hashdocumentByte = TEST.signed_hash(hash);
     
     PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(TEMP);
    FileOutputStream os2 = new FileOutputStream(DEST);
    ExternalSignatureContainer external2 = new 
    MyExternalSignatureContainer(hashdocumentByte,null);
    MakeSignature.signDeferred(reader2, "sig", os2, external2);
```

And in the server B where i sign the hash :

```
        BouncyCastleProvider providerBC = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Security.addProvider(providerBC);

        // we load our private key from the key store
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(CERTIFICATE), PIN);
        String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();
        Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, PIN);
        
        
     PrivateKeySignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA256", null);
       BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String hashAlgorithm = signature.getHashAlgorithm();
        System.out.println(hashAlgorithm);
        PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA256", null, digest, false);

        byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
        byte[] extSignature = signature.sign(sh);

        System.out.println(signature.getEncryptionAlgorithm());
        sgn.setExternalDigest(extSignature, null, signature.getEncryptionAlgorithm());
        return sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, null, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

Comment: Can you pls describe about "MyExternalSignatureContainer" class

Answer (score 0):

Your `signDocument` method apparently does not accept a pre-calculated hash value but seems to calculate the hash of the data you give it, in your case the (lower case) hex presentation of the hash value you already calculated.

In your first example document you have these values (all hashes are SHA256 hashes):

- Hash of the byte ranges to sign:

  ```
  91A9F5EBC4F2ECEC819898824E00ECD9194C3E85E4410A3EFCF5193ED7739119
  ```
- Hash of `"91a9f5ebc4f2ecec819898824e00ecd9194c3e85e4410a3efcf5193ed7739119".getBytes()`:

  ```
  2F37FE82F4F71770C2B33FB8787DE29627D7319EE77C6B5C48152F6E420A3242
  ```
- Hash value signed by the embedded signature container:

  ```
  2F37FE82F4F71770C2B33FB8787DE29627D7319EE77C6B5C48152F6E420A3242
  ```

And in your first example document you have these values (all hashes also are SHA256 hashes):

- Hash of the byte ranges to sign:

  ```
  79793C58489EB94A17C365445622B7F7945972A5A0BC4C93B6444BEDFFA5A5BB
  ```
- Hash of `"79793c58489eb94a17c365445622b7f7945972a5a0bc4c93b6444bedffa5a5bb".getBytes()`:

  ```
  A8BCBC6F9619ECB950864BFDF41D1B5B7CD33D035AF95570C426CF4B0405949B
  ```
- Hash value signed by the embedded signature container:

  ```
  A8BCBC6F9619ECB950864BFDF41D1B5B7CD33D035AF95570C426CF4B0405949B
  ```

Thus, you have to correct your `signDocument` method to interpret the data correctly, or you have to give it a byte array containing the whole range stream to digest.

Comment: unfortunately I am not able to modify the signDocument function, otherwise how can I do this?

Cause, when I check the signed hash before I integrate it into the original PDF I find the real hash that I passed as input

Comment: In fact for the signature I use a tool from an editor called LP7. So I call a jar file with inputs and return the signed file.
I don't know exactly what's going on the background

Comment: OK, I don't know LP7, and googl'ing for it I only find a turntable...

Comment: I just saw that the command you call is a batch file, `C:/Repo_LP7/lpcommand.bat`, so you can take a look and probably find out more...

Comment: The lpcomland.bat it’s just calling a lp7comman.jar, and the jar take the inputs file and sign. My problem i cannot see whats going on in the background

Comment: You might want to ask the supplier of that jar to explain how to use it to create a signature using a hash you already calculated.

Comment: Yes exactly, I am waiting for the response from the support
By the way is there a possibility to sign documents or hashes with open source solutions? if so do you have any examples?

Comment: The main question is where your private key is stored. If it's stored in a pkcs12 file (or something similar) or if you access it via some pkcs11 driver, you can sign with JRE alone already. If it's to be accessed via some proprietary means, it completely depends on these means.

Comment: Yes, I’m using a PKCS 12 certificate

Comment: In that case it indeed is much easier. First, though, which iText version exactly are you using? It looks like a 5.x, but is it a current 5.5.x or an older one?

Comment: Here is the exact version of iText used : 5.5.13.1

Comment: In that case please download the ["Digital Signatures for PDF Documents"](https://itextpdf.com/de/resources/books/digital-signatures-pdf) iText white paper and use   the `SignWithCAcert`example (code example 3.1 with 2.1), complete [here](https://github.com/itext/i5js-tutorial/blob/master/signatures/src/main/java/signatures/chapter3/C3_01_SignWithCAcert.java)

Comment: I am doing the example test using the link : https://github.com/itext/i5js-tutorial/tree/master/signatures

But i got always : 

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Comment: That means that you have multiple BouncyCastle versions in your class path. Please clean it to only contain the version required by iText.

Comment: I did the class test C3_01_SignWithCAcert it works very well but it only allows to sign PDFs and not hashes

Comment: *"but it only allows to sign PDFs and not hashes"* - but isn't that, i.e. signing PDFs, what you want to do?

Comment: My goal is to calculate a hash of a PDF document, sign the hash and then reintegrate the hash signed into the original PDF. I want to inform you that I want to put the hash calculation and the integration in a server A and the signature of the hash in a server B

Comment: I would propose that the signature you produce on server B shall be the whole CMS signature container to inject on server A. Then it is fairly trivial.

Comment: Ok it's done, and if i want to sign an XML file ? it's possible ?

Comment: I assume by *sign an XML file* you mean using enveloping or enveloped XML-DSIG signature. Such signatures are completely different, you don't have CMS signature containers but XML structures with similar functions but with many more options in creating them (and many more chances to shoot oneself in one's foot). In particular that should be the subject of a new question.

Comment: Im just putting a new question about this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63228884/how-can-i-sign-hash-of-xml-file-and-integrate-signature-in-original-file

Comment: can you help me please found a track i haven't found a result for a week

Comment: I know XML signatures only abstractly, not really hands-on. Thus, I doubt I can really help.