# Compare signed PDF with original (initial) PDF

Tags: java, itext, signature

After making a signature on a PDF document using iText, now I want to make a comparison between the signed document and the original document.

Normally I should have equality between the original document and the signed document (after deleting the signature I think).

How can i do that ?

UPDATE 1 :
here is the function I use for the moment which allows to delete the signature and after checking the two PDFs but the problem is that the return is always FALSE :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, 
 GeneralSecurityException, 
 DocumentException {

 testRemoveSignatureFromPDFSignedFirmaCerta();
 File file1 = new File(SRC);
 File file2 = new File(DEST_After_Delete);

 boolean compare1and2 = FileUtils.contentEquals(file1, file2);

 System.out.println("Are test1.txt and test2.txt the same? " + 
 compare1and2);

 }

 public static void testRemoveSignatureFromPDFSignedFirmaCerta() throws 
 IOException, GeneralSecurityException, DocumentException
 {

 try (   InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(DEST);
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new 
 File(DEST_After_Delete)))
 {
    Provider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(provider);

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputStream, null);
    AcroFields af = reader.getAcroFields();
    ArrayList<String> names = af.getSignatureNames();
    for (String name : names) {
        System.out.println("Signature name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Signature covers whole document: " + 
    af.signatureCoversWholeDocument(name));
        PdfPKCS7 pk = af.verifySignature(name, provider.getName());
        System.out.println("SignatureDate: " + pk.getSignDate());
        System.out.println("Certificate: " + pk.getSigningCertificate());
        System.out.println("Document modified: " + !pk.verify());
        af.removeField(name);
    }
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream, '\0');
    stamper.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @mkl do you have any idea about that ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Concerning your Update 1: If you read my answer, you would know that an approach like that has no chance at succeeding. If signing was not done in append mode / as incremental update, there essentially is no chance at all to retrieve the original, pre-signing PDF from the signed PDF.

Comment: Yes you are right. Using the code in the following link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62813684/integrate-signed-hash-into-original-pdf/62837505?noredirect=1#comment111403664_62837505. How can i force append mode ?

Comment: When creating the `PdfStamper` use `PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', null, true)` instead of `PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0')` to enforce append mode.

Comment: if i understood correctly, even if i will use append mode i cannot recover the original pdf from the signed pdf ? if not, is there a way how to do this ?

Comment: If you're signing in append mode, you can remove your changes by truncating the file where you started adding your changes.

Comment: Exactly, the code I put in UPDATE 1 allows to delete the signature but the problem is that by comparing the two documents (original and signed after deleting the signature) the function returns that it is not the same document.

Pareil pour la taille du document, j'ai remarqué que la taille du document initial est : 3Ko, le document signé 22ko et le document signé après signature est de 21Ko

Comment: I said *truncate* and I meant *truncate*. Don't *edit* the file. If you know the length of the original file, truncate there. If you don't know it, try and search the index of the second to last occurrence of "%%EOF" and truncate thereafter.

Comment: do you mean lenght of the original byte ?

Comment: The lenght of my original file is : 3028

Comment: @mkl I did some research but I can not find an example that allows you to truncate a specific part in the doculment. Most allow you to truncate an entire page

Comment: I mean, if you know the original length to be 3028 bytes, then simply take the first 3028 bytes of the signed file. This is not specific pdf handling, this is simple file I/O.

Comment: Very well. So according to you, this is the only solution to prove that the file passed in (original document) is indeed the one that was signed ?

Comment: The only one with an acceptable expenditure of time and resources. Otherwise one must walk the internal PDF object graph of the claimed original and the signed version and determine whether the objects are similar enough to make it plausible the documents are related. In particular if the signer applied many *arbitrary other changes* (see my answer), this might be difficult.

Comment: it is clear. otherwise I went on another idea is to recover the original hash from the PKCS7 except that I always find the hash of the document after modification. My question is is there no way to add the signature elements in the PDF but send the original pdf as a signature which will then be integrated into the modified document

Comment: My primary goal is basically to prove that the document that I received as input is signed without it being modified (apart from adding a signature)

Comment: To prove that you have to analyze the differences. Full stop. There is no short cut. This is difficult in case of signatures applied in append mode and very difficult otherwise. At least in general. If you know exactly which signing software is used in which signing mode, this might allow you to more easily identify the differences, making the task a moderate one.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

When generating integrated PDF signatures, you usually first prepare the PDF by

- selecting an existing or adding a new, empty signature field;
- adding a value dictionary to that field including a place holder for the signature container to embed eventually;
- (optionally) updating the existing or creating a new visualization for the signature;
- (optionally) rendering assorted other form fields read-only if the signature field has a signature lock dictionary;
- (optionally) creating and adding appearances to annotations if those annotations had no appearances yet, so there is no variability in the PDF appearance after signing; and
- (optionally) doing arbitrary other changes, e.g. repairs of invalid or questionable PDF objects etc.

Having saved this prepared PDF, you calculate the hash digest of the byte ranges to sign (essentially everything but the afore mentioned place holder), locally create or remotely request a signature container signing that hash value, and eventually you embed that signature container in the place holder.

There essentially are two ways to apply these changes:

- The PDF can be completely saved anew. In this case the objects modelling the original PDF may be substantially changed, their order in the document may change, compression may change, objects may be renumbered, etc etc etc.
- The changes are appended to the original PDF as an *incremental* update. In this case the start of the file remains the original PDF byte-by-byte.

*(If the signature is applied with iText: applying changes as an incremental update in iText is done by using the append mode.)*

In the former case a comparison is very difficult, in particular if there are lots of those "arbitrary other changes". Also you cannot expect to get back the original PDF by removing the signature, it may still be very different internally. I don't have an easy-to-implement idea here.

In the latter case you can easily check whether the signed file indeed is based on the unsigned one by testing whether as a file the signed PDF starts with the bytes of the unsigned one. An evaluation of the changes themselves, though, is difficult here, too.